# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException with Crop Activity

Tags: android, image, crop

I have an application where a user can upload an image for their user profile. In my application I allow the user to crop an image using the native cropper. However when I try to crop a large image I get the following error in my Logcat:

```
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
Exception when starting activity com.example.somename/com.example.somename.Profile
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
```

I start the cropper using the following bit of code:

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
cropIntent.setDataAndType(imageFileUri , "image/*");
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 265);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 265);
cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

then in my onActivityResult the following code gets the cropped image:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
imgDisplayPic.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
```

I am assuming the issue is with the cropper trying to send a large bitmap as a parcelable back to my activity. Is there any way around this? Or an alternative way to get a cropped image?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this problem I have managed to solve it with help from the following link: http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android. I solved the problem by implementing Option #2 found in the link.

As I had suspected originally the problem was send a large bitmap back from the cropper as a parcelable. Instead what I did (as the link suggests) is save the contents of the cropper into a temporary file and then read that content in my main activity/fragment. In order to not send the content back via parcelable the main change I had to do to my code above is

```
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
```

and added

```
cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempURI);
```

where "tempURI" is the Uri of the temp file where the contents of the cropper will be saved. Then in the onActivityResult you need to remove the following line

```
Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
```

Instead you will need some code to read the contents from your temporary file.

Hopes this helps anyone who comes across this problem.

EDIT:
Link is dead, try [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20120627040412/http://www.androidworks.com:80/crop_large_photos_with_android) one instead.